# Images from Sdcard to GridView?

Tags: android, image, gridview, sd-card, android-sdcard

In my android app I want to display in gridview images from a website. I have download the images in a folder from sdcard and now I need to put this images in an array for display on gridview. How can I do this? The code below is for only one image:

```
@Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            View MyView = convertView;

            if (convertView == null) {
                /* we define the view that will display on the grid */

                // Inflate the layout
                // LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
                LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) MyContext
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                MyView = li.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);

                // Add The Text!!!
                TextView tv = (TextView) MyView
                        .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_text);
                tv.setText("Item " + position);

                // Add The Image!!!
                ImageView iv = (ImageView) MyView
                        .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);

                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("sdcard/AndroidPlanet.png");
                iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

}
}
```

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036997/displaying-pictures-stored-on-the-sd-card-using-a-gridview

Comment: I didn't know...but I need some help,some answer

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at this and looping through the files in the directory.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29